# OpenAI GPT-3.5 "prompt" argument not working

Tags: http, openai-api, gpt-3

I am trying to make a flutter app with the openAI api that works like a chatbot, and I want to add a prompt so that the responses are more specialized, like in the openAI playground on their website.

I am testing the API post function with postman and it worked perfectly fine for me before I tried adding a prompt. I assumed that to add a prompt you just have to add a "prompt": line in the body like when you work with the text-davinci model, but when I do that I get this message returned:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unrecognized request argument supplied: prompt",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": null,
        "code": null
    }
}
```

Is there a different way you need to do this with the gpt models, or does the prompt argument just not exist for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OPEN AI 3.5-turbo model only supports the newer [chat completion API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create) which does not have a 'prompt' json body field.

I would assume you are using the older [competion API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create) json body format aginst the newer chat completion API endpoint and that is the reason for your error.

--- update ---

I can reproduce your exact error response with:

> curl https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions -H "Content-Type:
> application/json"  -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY"  -d '{
> "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo", "messages": [{"role": "user", "content":
> "Hello!"}], "prompt": "testing" }'

This is just a modified example from the api link above. Removing the added "prompt" field from the json makes it work fine.

So my advice in the comment stands.  Figure out what you are sending in the body of your http GET request.  It will have a "prompt" field, remove it and any other field that should not be there and it should work.

Comment: Yes, it has message array key for each objet can be user, system and assistant

Comment: Nowhere in the chat completion API json body format does it have a field called 'prompt'.  Check the API docs and compare with your http get request body what you send to openai to see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: That is what I was thinking was the problem. Is there any way to emulate this functionality, or is It just not possible